# Angular 7: Going to any URL initially forces the browser to redirect to the home component

Tags: angular, reload

I have a project I'm working on written with Angular 7.2.0.

When I try to go to a specific page initially, for example:

```
http://localhost:4200/comics?sort=series
```

then Angular always redirects the browser to the root:

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

But I can interact with the app to go the desired page.

My app-routing.module.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: MainPageComponent },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountPageComponent, canActivate: [ReaderGuard] },
  { path: 'duplicates', component: DuplicatesPageComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
  { path: 'comics', component: LibraryPageComponent, canActivate: [ReaderGuard] },
  { path: 'comics/:id', component: ComicDetailsComponent, canActivate: [ReaderGuard] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I would like to be able to share a link to a specific comic view, but going to such a link always redirects the user to the home component.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: With that much information, It does not seem that the error can be producable

Comment: Could it be something in your ReaderGuard?

Comment: This seems to be caused by the CanActivate guards being fired before the app has had a chance to retrieve the user object from the backend. So it's not the routing per se but the guards being invoked before the Angular app has finished retrieving the user's information and authorizations. This call is finishing after the router has decided the user doesn't have access to the route and redirects them back to the home page.

Comment: @MikeOne Yeah, that seems to be the core of the problem. If I remove them then the pages reload correctly, but I lose some of the protections for URLs that I want to have in place.

Comment: So maybe you can post a new question about your Guard?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the ReaderGuard/AdminGuard not having the user's details when the route it processed. Going to open another question for that instead.